# Facebook Ads Error : You can't call show() for ad in state LOADING

Tags: android, facebook-ads-api

I'm integrating Facebook Ads in my app following their official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-interstitial). But when I run my app I get the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can't call show() for ad in state LOADING. You can change Integration Error mode by setting AdSettings.setIntegrationErrorMode()
    at com.facebook.ads.internal.c.a.a(Unknown Source:122)
    at com.facebook.ads.internal.c.f.a(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd.show(Unknown Source:2)
    at tech.grapegames.pdfreader.ui.MainActivity.moveToFragment(MainActivity.java:115)
    at tech.grapegames.pdfreader.ui.HomeFragment.onClick(HomeFragment.java:85)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Below is my code

```
private com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd fbInterstitialAd;
fbInterstitialAd = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(this, getString(R.string.fb_interstitial_ad_id));
fbInterstitialAd.loadAd();
```

and I'm showing it like below

```
if (fbInterstitialAd.isAdLoaded() && !fbInterstitialAd.isAdInvalidated()) {
fbInterstitialAd.show();//This line causes the crash
```

This is the dependency that I've added in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong dependency. Replace the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.0.1'
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi: you need to check if your ad is not null and if it is loaded before show it:

`if(fbInterstitialAd != null && fbInterstitialAd.isAdLoaded()) fbInterstitialAd.show();`

Answer (score 2):

I updated the facebook ads from 5.0.1 to 5.3.1 and I have the same error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can't call load() for ad in state LOADING. Previous states: LOADING << CREATED. You can change Integration Error mode by setting AdSettings.setIntegrationErrorMode()
```

This error happened when you trying to load a new ad when the previous is loading.
What did they smoke when writing code? They should redirect the error to "onError" method, but they decide to throw an IllegalStateException

**My solution is not elegant, but it is working**:

```
// load the ad
public void load() {
    if (interstitialAd != null) {
        try {
            interstitialAd.loadAd();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Do nothing, just skip and wait for ad loading
        }
    }
}

// show the ad
public void show() {
    if (interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.isAdLoaded()) {
        try {
            interstitialAd.show();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Do nothing, just skip and wait for ad loading
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 fb_interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
            Toast.makeText(VideoStatusActivity.this, "Display", 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
            fb_interstitialAd.loadAd();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {

        }
    });
```